# Error in wp.logistic: ‘p0’ must be numeric in (0,1)? What to do when p0 is negative?

Tags: probability, logistic, statistical-power, binary-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I am trying to find out the sample size I need for a future study using a reanalysed existing dataset to enter the values in a WebPower script. I am using the intercept and odds ratio/estimate of my multiple logistic regression model for p0 and p1:

```r
Call:
glm(formula = GameOutcome_Num ~ GroupStat_Num * 
     AgeClass_Num * 
    GameType_Num, family = binomial(link = 
    "logit"), data = mv_num, 
    weights = na.action(na.omit))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.9728  -1.0682   0.5553   0.9925   2.2101  

Coefficients:
                                            Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                                 -0.06412    0.19502  -0.329  0.742302    
GroupStat_Num1                               0.82307    0.28887   2.849  0.004382 ** 
AgeClass_Num.L                               0.46837    0.34405   1.361  0.173407    
AgeClass_Num.Q                               0.05050    0.33140   0.152  0.878875    
GameType_Num1                                1.08302    0.30443   3.558  0.000374 ***
GameType_Num2                               -1.38288    0.31330  -4.414 0.0000102 ***
GroupStat_Num1:AgeClass_Num.L               -0.06699    0.51410  -0.130  0.896329    
GroupStat_Num1:AgeClass_Num.Q                0.32545    0.48620   0.669  0.503260    
GroupStat_Num1:GameType_Num1                -1.34768    0.42780  -3.150  0.001631 ** 
GroupStat_Num1:GameType_Num2                -0.64915    0.47986  -1.353  0.176124    
AgeClass_Num.L:GameType_Num1                 0.95638    0.52603   1.818  0.069046 .  
AgeClass_Num.Q:GameType_Num1                -0.62513    0.52853  -1.183  0.236904    
AgeClass_Num.L:GameType_Num2                -1.11864    0.55656  -2.010  0.044440 *  
AgeClass_Num.Q:GameType_Num2                -0.20390    0.52837  -0.386  0.699564    
GroupStat_Num1:AgeClass_Num.L:GameType_Num1 -0.17610    0.75343  -0.234  0.815197    
GroupStat_Num1:AgeClass_Num.Q:GameType_Num1  0.44247    0.72832   0.608  0.543506    
GroupStat_Num1:AgeClass_Num.L:GameType_Num2  2.22782    0.87490   2.546  0.010885 *  
GroupStat_Num1:AgeClass_Num.Q:GameType_Num2 -0.19693    0.78495  -0.251  0.801900    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 951.74  on 686  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 779.16  on 669  degrees of freedom
AIC: 815.16

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Here I am trying to find the sample size I would need to replicate the GroupStat_Num1 effect. I am using the values from intercept and GroupStat_Num1:

```r
wp.logistic(n = NULL, p0 =-0.06412, p1=0.82307, alpha = 0.05, power =
0.9, alternative = c("two.sided"), family
=c('binomial'), parameter=0.5)
```

However that returns this error:

```r
Error in wp.logistic(n = NULL, p0 = -0.06412, p1 = 0.82307, alpha = 0.05, : 
‘p0’ must be numeric in (0,1)
```

How should I proceed here?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the help file for wp.logistic, it says:
p0
Prob(Y=1|X=0): the probobility of observieng 1 for the outcome variable Y when the predictor X equals 0.

p1
Prob(Y=1|X=1): the probobility of observieng 1 for the outcome variable Y when the predictor X equals 1.

p0 and p1 are probabilities, and can't be negative.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much! Do you know how I can find/generate these values from an existing glm?

Comment: It appears to me that the function is for testing power for a single binary predictor. You have a pile of predictors.